# How to Find Customers that have logged in over N number of times during a month?

Tags: datetime, count, teradata, distinct, date-arithmetic

I have this table logins with the following schema:

```
id
cust_id 
login_date
```

I am trying to find the number of customers that have logged in at least three times within a week period during a given timeframe. I have tried a self join statement and have found that it creates a few errors. Code in question:

```
SELECT count(distinct(l1.cust_id))
FROM login l1
JOIN login l2 
ON l1.cust_id = l2.cust_ID
AND l1.id <> l2.ID
AND l2.login_date BETWEEN l1.login_date AND l1.login_date + interval '7' day  
JOIN login l3
ON l2.cust_id = l3.cust_id 
AND l1.id <> l3.id
AND l2.id <> l3.id 
AND l3.login_date BETWEEN l1.login_date AND l1.login_date + interval '7' day 
WHERE l1.login_date between '2020-10-01' AND '2020-10-31';  /* for the month of oct*/
```

I am worried that, I am going to over extend the number of logins that occurs during this session. EX: if a user logs in four times, 1 will join with 2, 3, 4. 2 with 3, 4 and 3 with 4.

What would be a better way to perform this query or am I on the right path with my logic?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: MySQL, Oracle, Postgresql...?

Comment: Added the database type

Answer (score 1):

You could use window functions and a range frame specification:

```
select count(distinct cust_id) cnt
from (
    select l.*,
        count(*) over(
            partition by cust_id
            order by login_date
            range between interval '7' day preceding and current row
        ) cnt_last_7d
    from login
    where login_date >= date '2020-10-01' 
      and login_date <  date '2020-11-01'
) t
where cnt_last_7d >= 3
```

For each row in the table, the window function counts how many times the same user logged in over the last 7 day. All that is left to do is use that information for filtering, and count the related users.

You did not tell which database you are running, so this uses standard date arithmetic and date literals. You might need to adapt it to your actual database.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `lag()`.

```
select distinct cust_id
from (select l.*,
             lag(login_date, 2) over (partition by cust_id) as login_date_2
      from login l
      where l.login_date >= '2020-10-01' and
            l.login_date < '2020-11-01'
     ) l
where login_date < login_date_2 + interval '7 day';
```

This just looks at the *second* previous login for each customer.  And then compares that to the current login.